# Is there a way to get the current version deployed via my app store?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I wanted to know if anyone knows of a way you can get the current version deployed via the app store, I'm trying to create an update pop up in my app where I can compare the deployed version via the app store and the user's current version.

Comment: I already have that, which does not solve what I'm trying to do. Not all users will update their app I need a way to check their current version which I have as a var in my app and the current or latest version on the app store. This way if they don't match I can show a message to update the app

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood.  You want to know the version that is available in the app store, I thought you were asking for the version that the user has.

Comment: Yes in the app store, so I can compare

Comment: For the Apple App Store you can use the search API to get information about your app, including the version, in JSON format. See https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#searching

Comment: Standard practice is to put an XML or JSON file on a server somewhere that you update yourself, and check the current version in the app by reading this file.  There are also libraries such as this one that uses Jsoup to parse the Play Store html page for your app: https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/Android-Update-Checker

Comment: html XML is perfect for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this module https://github.com/kimxogus/react-native-version-check
By this module, you can find current version

Set Your APP_ID and APP_NAME

```
VersionCheck.setAppID(APP_ID);                    // Your App ID for App Store URL
VersionCheck.setAppName(APP_NAME);                // Your App Name for App Store URL


console.log(VersionCheck.getCurrentVersion());  // You get app current install version  

VersionCheck.getLatestVersion()
  .then(latestVersion => {
    console.log(latestVersion);  //You will get app latest Version from app store
});
```